# directadmin nginx+apache webserver reverse proxy configuration for subdomain

Tags: apache, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, directadmin

I have read through this link:
https://help.poralix.com/articles/nginx-to-proxy-requests-to-custom-port-in-directadmin
and it worked as stated. but there is a problem.
the author fixes the problem by redirecting requests to example.net to 127.0.0.1:3000. what I want is to redirect requests to subdomain.example.net to 128.0.0.1:3000.

and I want everything done through directadmin nginx+apache configuration as stated in the above link.
can anyone help me with this?

I have tried creating a real subdomain(within directadmin) but a real subdomain wont show up in the Custom `HTTPD Configurations` domain section (which is one of the required steps in the above document).

I have tried creating the subdomain.example.net as first level domain in direct admin, it apparently works but there are two problems with this approach
first the subdomain.example.net is not inside public_html as a normal subdomain would, so i guess its not officially considered a subdomain
second I get `CORS` erros which i dont like debuggin...

any suggestions?